# My buttons wont appear in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Can anyone help me. i am facing the below issue:
I am developing a game that is about questions and answers.
i used widget API to add buttons.
in menu screen (Menu.lua) i added 2 buttons for now. Play and options.
once i press play it go to the 1st level.

now the problem is as below:
1- once i add the buttons to the groupScene. they disappear.
2- once  i remove them from groupScene they will appear. and will appear in the next seen.

so what should i do. should i remove them one by one. or is there another solution.

code as below

1- Main.Lua

```
 `W = display.viewableContentWidth
H = display.viewableContentHeight
local widget = require( "widget")
local composer = require("composer" )
composer.purgeOnSceneChange = true
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

-- most commonly used screen coordinates
centerX = display.contentCenterX
centerY = display.contentCenterY
screenLeft = display.screenOriginX
screenWidth = display.contentWidth - screenLeft * 2
screenRight = screenLeft + screenWidth
screenTop = display.screenOriginY
screenHeight = display.contentHeight - screenTop * 2
screenBottom = screenTop + screenHeight
display.contentWidth = screenWidth
display.contentHeight = screenHeight


local bg = display.newRect( 0, 0, 2000,3000 )
bg:setFillColor( .26, .26, .26 )

composer.gotoScene( "Menu",{effect = "slideDown"} )
```

`

2- Menu.lua

```
    local sceneName = ...
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene("Menu")

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- All code outside of the listener functions will only be executed ONCE unless "composer.removeScene()" is called
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Local forward references should go here

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local function tapped(event)

    local id = event.target.id


    if id == "Start" then
        composer.gotoScene( "Level1", {effect = "slideDown"}   )
        print("Level 1")


    else
        composer.gotoScene( "About_Us", {effect = "slideDown"}   )
            print("about us")
end
end

-- "scene:create()"
function scene:create( event )

    local widget = require( "widget")
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Initialize the scene here
    -- Example: add display objects to "sceneGroup", add touch listeners, etc.
    --local title = display.newText( "abed" , centerX, centerY ,"Helvetica", 20 )

    ------------------------------------------start
 startButton = widget.newButton {
    id = "Start", 
    onRelease = tapped,
    defaultFile = "button.png",
    overFile = "buttonclicked.png",
    label = "إبدأ اللعبة",
    labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } },

} 
startButton.x=centerX
startButton.y = centerY+-50
--sceneGroup:insert( startButton )
------------------------------------------options
 optionbutton = widget.newButton {
    id = "options", 
    onRelease = tapped,
    defaultFile = "button.png",
    overFile = "buttonclicked.png",
    label = "خيارات",
    labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } }
} 
optionbutton.x=centerX
optionbutton.y = centerY+50
--sceneGroup:insert( optionbutton )



--local start = display.newImageRect( [parent,], filename, [baseDir,], width, height )
end


-- "scene:show()"
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
-------------------------------------------code

    end
end


-- "scene:hide()"
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    local phase = event.phase


    if ( phase == "will" ) then

        -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen)
        -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene
        -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, etc.
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called immediately after scene goes off screen
    end
end


-- "scene:destroy()"
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Called prior to the removal of scene's view
    -- Insert code here to clean up the scene
    -- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.


end


-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

3- Level1.lua

```
    local sceneName = ...
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene("Level1")

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- All code outside of the listener functions will only be executed ONCE unless "composer.removeScene()" is called
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local function tapped(event)
    local id = event.target.id


    if id == "option1" then
        local answerCover = display.newRect( centerX, centerY, 400, 35)
        answerCover:setFillColor( .26, .26, .26 )
        local title = display.newText( "لقد ربحت" , centerX, centerY ,"Helvetica", 20 )
        composer.gotoScene( "About_Us")
    end
    if id == "Option2" then
          local answerCover = display.newRect( centerX, centerY, 400, 35)
        answerCover:setFillColor( .26, .26, .26 )
        local title = display.newText( "لقد خسرت" , centerX, centerY ,"Helvetica", 20 )
    end
    if id == "Option3" then
          local answerCover = display.newRect( centerX, centerY, 400, 35)
        answerCover:setFillColor( .26, .26, .26 )
        local title = display.newText( "لقد خسرت" , centerX, centerY ,"Helvetica", 20 )
    end
    if id == "option4" then
          local answerCover = display.newRect( centerX, centerY, 400, 35)
        answerCover:setFillColor( .26, .26, .26 )
        local title = display.newText( "لقد خسرت" , centerX, centerY ,"Helvetica", 20 )
    end
end



-- Local forward references should go here

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-- "scene:create()"
function scene:create( event )
        local widget = require( "widget")
    local sceneGroup = self.view

local Q = display.newImageRect( "Questions/Q1.png", 300, 150 )
Q.x = centerX
Q.y = centerY-150

------------------------------------------option1
local option1 = widget.newButton {
    id = "option1", 
    onRelease = tapped,
    defaultFile = "button.png",
    overFile = "buttonclicked.png",
    label = "12",
    labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } }
} 
option1.x=centerX
option1.y = screenBottom-180
--sceneGroup:insert(option1)
------------------------------------------option2
local option2 = widget.newButton {
    id = "Option2", 
    onRelease = tapped,
    defaultFile = "button.png",
    overFile = "buttonclicked.png",
    label = "5",
    labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } }
} 
option2.x=centerX
option2.y = screenBottom - 130


------------------------------------------option3
local option3 = widget.newButton {
    id = "Option3", 
    onRelease = tapped,
    defaultFile = "button.png",
    overFile = "buttonclicked.png",
    label = "9",
    labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } }
} 
option3.x=centerX
option3.y = screenBottom-80

------------------------------------------option4
local option4 = widget.newButton {
    id = "option4", 
    onRelease = tapped,
    defaultFile = "button.png",
    overFile = "buttonclicked.png",
    label = "4",
    labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } }
} 
option4.x=centerX
option4.y = screenBottom -30

    -- Initialize the scene here
    -- Example: add display objects to "sceneGroup", add touch listeners, etc.
   -- local title = display.newText( "abed" , centerX, centerY ,"Helvetica", 20 )


end


-- "scene:show()"
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is now on screen
        -- Insert code here to make the scene come alive
        -- Example: start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
    end
end


-- "scene:hide()"
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen)
        -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene
        -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, etc.
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called immediately after scene goes off screen
    end
end


-- "scene:destroy()"
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Called prior to the removal of scene's view
    -- Insert code here to clean up the scene
    -- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.
end


-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You've included a good deal of code which might decrease your chances of getting people to read it all.  Please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and see if you can reduce the amount of code.

Comment: Too much code but I think I had this problem, most likely you dont add them in the right order. If you hide something and then add your button that group that will also be invisible.